# How do a browser find the destination of general address such as http://diskstation:5000?

Tags: networking, home-networking, nas

During setting synology NAS I just get curious how it works.

The NAS can be accessed by another computer on the network with the address
"http://diskstation:5000"or "http://find.synology.com".

I don't know how this works...

I guessted that the NAS may get an arbitrary IP using DHCP (this might be also wrong), but... how that can be accessed with "http://diskstation:5000"?...

Can anyone help me to understand what is going on?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

There are several possibilities:

#### DHCP

DHCP clients often report their own hostname as part of the address lease request, and many home routers maintain an internal DNS domain (e.g. `.lan` or `.home`) based on these hostnames.

For example: When the device reports that its hostname is "diskstation" and obtains an address via DHCP, the router adds an internal DNS entry `diskstation.home` with the address it leased.

When *your computer* obtains an address via DHCP, the router also informs that the local DNS suffix is ".home" and therefore `diskstation` should be expanded to `diskstation.home`, which then can be resolved through the router's internal DNS server.

#### Local names

Many devices support serverless name resolution using Apple's mDNS, Microsoft's NetBIOS or LLMNR. When the browser needs to resolve a dotless name like `diskstation`, instead of asking DNS the operating system broadcasts the query on the local LAN network  and waits for any random device to reply.

I don't know whether Synology NAS firmware supports LLMNR or NetBIOS, but it certainly supports [mDNS](https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/help/DSM/AdminCenter/file_service_discovery). Generally mDNS names are always in the form of `<name>.local` instead of dotless, but the recently-added mDNS implementation in Windows 10 actually accepts both versions.

#### Website

Finally, the "find.synology.com" website does nothing magic at all. It just tries to redirect you to the first address you mentioned (`http://diskstation.local:5000`). If that doesn't work, it redirects to `http://rackstation.local:5000`, then to `http://synologyrouter.local:5000`, and so on. Either it finds the correct address by trial-and-error or it doesn't.

Of course, for this to work, one of the above methods (mDNS or LLMNR) must already be active.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! 
I was somewhat overwhelmed by your thorough and kind answers. ^^; 
I learned a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I can't add any additional information to grawity's answer, but your router is the place where you're most likely to find out. (Enter the IP into your browser)

Windows:

```
    ipconfig | findstr /i "Gateway"
```

*nix:

```
    ip route | grep default
```